# Best practice for adding 'dynamic' fields in GraphQL?

Tags: graphql

I have a GraphQL API that provides information about YouTube videos. One of the fields I  set up is the YouTube video ID (e.g. dQw4w9WgXcQ), and from that, you can deduce the video URL (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ) and thumbnail e.g.

If I didn't want to store the URL as its own field and still wanted to have a field called 'videoUrl' that constructs the URL on the fly as part of the response, do I just splice that in at the resolver level after the database query, or is there a better way?

So the resolver could look something like this:

```
recentVideos: async (_parent, _args, ctx) => {
   const videos = await ctx.prisma.video.findMany({
      orderBy: {
         publishedAt: 'desc',
      },
      take: 24 });

   return videos.map(video => { videoUrl: `https://youtube.com/watch?v=${video.youtubeId}`, ...video });
}
```

As long as I set up videoUrl as a String in the type definition too, is this a solid practice? In this scenario, it would always do the work of populating the videoUrl field, regardless of whether it's part of the result fields or not.

PS: The sample youtube video I'm using here is Never Gonna Give You Up, don't say you haven't been warned!